# Altium: How to select/highlight a net and then move to every sheet that have this net?

Tags: schematics, altium

I am trying to find where a certain net exists by selecting it in one sheet, and then move to all the sheets where this net is present.

How to do that in Altium?

I am using version 22.10.11.

Comment: This link will take you, with a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: [https://forum.live.altium.com/](https://forum.live.altium.com/)

Comment: thank you will check it out!

Comment: Do you mean for nets that have been named using net labels?

Answer (score 0):

Us the Insight feature:

open your Altium preferences and activate "Enable Document Insight" and "Enable Project Insight". When you leave your mouse curser on a net for some seconds The Insight will show you every page of your project where this net is connected to.